# Override Odoo makeActionManager function in action_service.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo, overriding, odoo-15

Is there a way to override _triggerDownload js function inside the parent function (makeActionManager function )  inside the action_service.js?

we have :

```
makeActionManager(){
          _triggerDownload (){
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way but in order to use it you will need to provide your complete version of the file `action_service.js` and remove the Odoo version of the file from the assets bundle in order to use your version. In previous Odoo versions this was easier because you could do it using a view inheritance to remove the Odoo script tag definition using XPATH. Since Odoo 15 that have been changed into defining the assets at the module manifest level and it's tricky now and I haven't had a chance to review the changes around that part yet. I will definitely need to look at that in order to solve other Odoo assets related issues that heavily depends on the way the assets bundles are defined and precessed in Odoo